# how to access the binded value from href in angular2

Tags: angular

Am using Angular2 . And in my project I used like

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" width="500">
    <tr><th>NAME</th>
    <th>Value</th>  
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor = "let d of Data">
        <td><a href="#/pages/Update?id={{d.name}}">{{d.name}}</a></td><td>{{d.value}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

When click on the name it will be passed with the URL . But the problem is how it can be displayed in another page template. 
I want to access it another page template and it must be displayed in table. How can I make it possible ..??

Comment: what do you want to display in another component? ("But the problem is how it can be displayed in another page template")

Comment: I want to dispaly the {{d.name}} in next Update page template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide an ActivatedRoute object and a Router object in the constructor of the component you want to use the value in.

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router
) {}
```

Then you can access the value in the component

```
this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
      this.foo = params['id'];
});
```

After that you can use it in a table just like you did in your example.

Comment: thanks for the fast response @Jarkob . But it doesn;t work for me . It (this.foo) alerting a null value .

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake.
My example should work if you change your <a> to 

`<a [routerLink]="['#/pages/Update/', d.name]" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
              {{d.name}}
</a>`

Comment: I edit my code as you said @Jarkob . But it will not go to Update , it will redirected to dashboard

Comment: <td><a [routerLink]="['#/pages/Update/', d.name]" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">{{d.name}}</a></td> .. Same as You said

Comment: No, I meant your app-routing.module.ts or any ...-routing.module.ts file which is responsible for the routing on that page.

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'pages', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];

Comment: Alright, I think you need to change your <a> to `<a [routerLink]="['/pages/', d.name]" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"> {{d.name}} </a>`
 Or do you have a pages-routing.module.ts as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `@Injectable` service class and save `d.name` in a variable in that class. You can then inject that class to any component and once the user clicked on the `d.name`, set that variable in that class with the new value